# How to slice every element of array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of elements: [AdsAyush, AdsFace, AdsKicks, AdsMac]
I want to slice every element of this array (**remove Ads**) and get the result as [Ayush, Face, Kicks, Mac].

How can I slice the "Ads" from every element of this array.

I am doing something like this:

```
array.forEach(element =>
  return element.toString().slice(3);
```

But this is giving me error and not sure what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.map` as follows.

```js
const array = ["AdsAyush", "AdsFace", "AdsKicks", "AdsMac"];
const result = array.map(element => element.slice(3));

console.log(result);
```